# How block a call in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, autocomplete

I'm writing an autocomplete in which every time i write a word in a input text i call a function

```
<input data-ng-model="search.searchText" data-ng-change="search.results()" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

so every time i type a word starts a call to `search.results()` that fill an array of json with results i need.. this is only method i can use because the query is dynamic. So i will have a json that it creates like:

```
http://www.test.com/search&test=....
```

where after `test=` go the test i'm writing. This is a problem because it starts many calls! i need stop the previews calls if start another one. How can i do it?

this is the function in angularjs

```
$scope.search.results = function(){
      $scope.search.res.getAutocompleteResults({

        }, function (data) {
            if ($scope.search.searchText.length > 0) {
                self.searchResults = data.item; //filling the array

            } else {
                self.searchResults = [];

            }
        })};
```

Comment: Do you want to create a server call for each change?

Comment: The problem is that in this way if i type faster i have 4/5/6 etc.. calls in background. I need find a solution to block the other calls if start another. Something like that

Comment: Well you can abort ajax calls, but it seems like you just need to debounce the function. Look at underscore or lodash debounce. It makes sure the function is only called once per a certain amount of time

Comment: i don't know if could be the correct way the debounce.. how could abort the calls by the way?